# Silverlight audio player control

Tags: silverlight, media-player

I am looking for Silverlight audio player with opened source code. Can anybody suggest good open source solution? For now I stopped on slaudio player, but it has few bugs(((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find nothing better than SMF.